# Adding Video to iPad Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, ipad

I'm trying to get some video added to my iPad 3.2 simulator's library, so I can test my app.

I converted a video using QuickTime, called it VID_0001.MOV, and copied it to the Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Media/DCIM/APPLE100 folder.

This video worked for the iPhone simulator, but it's not working on the 3.2 (iPad) simulator; it doesn't show up in a UIImagePicker.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder name is 100APPLE, not APPLE100.

I found this post helpful (cache because the original is dead): http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Y_80lhkJBloJ:silentmac.com/%3Fp%3D498%26cpage%3D1+iphone+simulator+video+trimming&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a

Update: Cache died as well. Too bad.